# How to get the name of the last mounted/unmounted filesystem

Tags: linux, mount, notifications

I'm know I can monitor (using [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), or [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)) on the files `/proc/mount` or `/etc/mtab` and findout **WHEN** a filesystem is mounted or unmounted. Also I can use [getmntent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getmntent.3.html) for getting a list of mounted filesystems.

My app is intended to monitor the mounted filesystem and report any change (mount or unmount).

My solution:

1. Detect some change in `/proc/mounts`.
2. Get all currently mounted filesystem with `getmntent`.
3. Compare the obtained list with some previous list.
4. Process the difference.

But I need to know if there are some way to get the last filesystem mounted when polling from `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/mtab`. Just reading the file or polling data into some structure (like `mntent` for instance.)

Comment: The Audit framework and the associated user space daemon, `auditd`, is the right tool for monitoring system calls, including `mount(2)`, I think.

Comment: It is a good tool, but I don't want my app to depend on others.